# Is "Altermesh", a geometry nodes port to Unreal Engine legally allowed to be used in a commercial game/project?

Tags: geometry-nodes, unreal-engine, licensing

Altermesh https://altermesh.com/ https://youtu.be/IvAZXnK8xcU?t=543 is a plugin that delivers the power of Blenders geometry nodes project in Unreal Engine. You create your geometry nodes node graph in Blender > import it into Unreal and you end up with a dynamic mesh generated at editor & runtime directly in Unreal (allowing you to speed up the level design process as well as create dynamic worlds driven by Unreal Blueprint logic).

In general all this looks quite fancy, but assuming that the developer pulled this off by refitting code from the geometry nodes project for the actual geometry generation, **what am I actually allowed to use AlterMesh for whilst staying within legal boundaries? Is Altermesh even legally allowed to exist in the first place considering that Unreal Engine isnt exactly GPL compatible (right?)?**

I would assume that I wouldnt be able to ship a game that contains portions of Blenders code base, without licensing my game under a GPL compatible license (that would essentially force me to open source my game), correct? If so, **does that mean that AlterMesh usecase is really limited to things like video/movie creation** where I never really distribute the Unreal Engine project itself in any way - but rather content created using the project (again, video/images)?

If AlterMesh had an option to exist only at editor-time & create static meshes substituting the dynamically generated meshes for shipping builds - whilst excluding itself or at the very least code reused from Blender in shipping builds. Would that make any difference in how Im allowed to use AlterMesh (say, would that allow me to distribute a game made using Altermesh, whilst maintaining freedom of licensing my game under a proprietary GPL incompatible license?)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off topic because it is about licensing and legal issues we are neither equipped nor legally qualified to answer, and any ill advice could unintentionally pose a liability to both the user and the network. For official info see the [Blender Licensing Terms and Conditions](https://www.blender.org/about/license/) and the [FAQ about GNU GPL](https://www.blender.org/support/faq/#gnu-gpl)

Comment: I'm not exactly a lawyer either, so its kind of difficult for me to be able to drag any conclusions by the licenses alone. Afaik theres no better place to bring this topic up (if not polycount or similar)?

Comment: Lots of better places for this type of discussion, starting with https://law.stackexchange.com, perhaps [Blender Artists Forum](https://blenderartists.org/) or even their own Altermesh Discord. Albeit "*assuming that the developer pulled this off by refitting code from the geometry nodes*" is a bad assumption to star any serious discussion about it anywhere. Without knowing what is actually under the hood everything said will be pure speculation.

Comment: Their paid plan also claims to offer access to source code, which indicates at least some level of compliance with the GPL.